# For the case of two goods, give an example of preferences that are represnted by a continuous utility function that allows for fat indifference curves

Tags: microeconomics, mathematical-economics, utility, preferences

The question in the title sounds like a trick question, due to the monotonicity property that indifference curves have, such that for two goods x and y, strong monotonicity implies y > x.

Possible that you could answer the question by stipulating the area under a curve?

Comment: You should specify every one of your assumptions/conditions more clearly. In particular, do you require strong monotonicity?

Answer (score 2):

$$u(x, y) = 2$$
is a simple example of a continuous utility function with thick indifference curve.

\begin{eqnarray*} u(x, y)= \begin{cases} x & x < 1 \\ 1  & 1 \leq x < 2 \\ x - 1 & x \geq 2 \end{cases} \end{eqnarray*}

is another continuous utility function with thick indifference curve for $u=1$.

Answer (score 2):

How about a utility function that only enjoys discrete quantities. This takes discrete values but allows for continuous inputs.

$$U(x,y) = (floor(x))^{\alpha} \cdot (floor(y))^{1-\alpha}$$

[image]

```
    import numpy as np
    import seaborn as sns
    import pandas as pd
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    x = np.arange(0, 10, 0.01)
    y = np.arange(0, 10, 0.01)
    alpha = 0.7

    xv, yv = np.meshgrid(x, y)

    def U(x1,y1, alpha1):
        return(np.floor(x1)**alpha1 * np.floor(y1)**(1-alpha1))

    uv = U(xv,yv, alpha)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    CS = ax.contourf(xv, yv,uv, levels=np.unique(uv))
    ax.set_xlabel('x')
    ax.set_ylabel('y')
    plt.colorbar(CS)
    plt.show()
```

If it must be strongly monotonic and differentiable, then no, I believe this is impossible. An agent's preferences are said to be strongly monotonic if, given a consumption bundle $x$, the agent prefers all consumption bundles $y$ that have more of at least one good, and not less in any other good. That is $y\geq x$ and $y\neq x$
imply $y\succ x$. If this is a continuous and differentiable utility function then this means:
$$ \frac{\partial U}{\partial X_{i}} > 0 \: \forall i$$
This implies that the indifference curves cannot be fat. Consider being on a thin indifference curve and, holding fixed x, increasing y by an infinitesimal amount. This will increase utility by  $\frac{\partial U}{\partial y}$, which we just stipulated is positive. So you must be moving onto a higher indifference curve and therefore it is not "fat" in the y direction. Similarly, taking an infinitesimal step in the x direction holding fixed y increase utility by  $\frac{\partial U}{\partial x}$, which we also just stipulated is positive. So this utility function cannot have fat indifference curves.

I am unsure if this also is true for non-differentiable utility functions.

Comment: But this again violates (strong) monotonicity.